# Atypical tetrads

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

[ADDITION]

I am wanting to expand Douthett's "4-cube trio" graph to include more tetrads (https://books.google.com/books?id=5a6mVvjvn5MC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=tesseract+trio+douthett&source=bl&ots=vONIEw7N-E&sig=mM7nRmClr0u45Ps63JwG6_e2kb8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x8uhVNAZy7-CBLHggLAM&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tesseract%20trio%20douthett&f=false). I could just use numbers, but wanted to give them good names instead, reflecting their harmonic functions. I'm a bit rusty, though. Most of the added tetrads were not difficult to identify, but the following have been giving me some trouble.

[ORIGINAL]

Please help me identify the "best" harmonic label for any of the following tetrads (don't care about inversion). I've noticed each is only a half-step away from a more-identifiable tetrad.

(Outside any musical context. Assume the usual 12-ET. Any enharmonic spelling or note ordering is okay.)

C G B F (C-M9sus4? C-M11?)

Ab C E B

Ab C E Bb

G B D# A#

B Eb Gb Bb

C Gb Bb D

F C Eb Bb

B E Gb Bb

Bb F C E (Bb-M11? Bb-Aug11?)

C# G B D# (C#-m11flat5?)

C# E B F#

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Where are these coming from? Can you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve here? As written, this isn't really a good question for SE--it would be much better if somehow we could help you solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: It is not homework. I am wanting to expand Douthett's "4-cube trio" graph to include more tetrads (https://books.google.com/books?id=5a6mVvjvn5MC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=tesseract+trio+douthett&source=bl&ots=vONIEw7N-E&sig=mM7nRmClr0u45Ps63JwG6_e2kb8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x8uhVNAZy7-CBLHggLAM&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tesseract%20trio%20douthett&f=false). I could just use numbers, but I wanted to give them good names instead, reflecting their harmonic functions. I'm a bit rusty, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C G B F (C-M9sus4? C-M11?) C Maj7 add 4, or C Maj11

Ab C E B - Ab aug add #9

Ab C E Bb - Ab aug add 2

G B D# A# - G aug add #9

B Eb Gb Bb - Ebmin add #5 (first inversion)

C Gb Bb D - C9 add b5

F C Eb Bb - F7 add 4 (could be major or minor)

B E Gb Bb - 057e (12-tone)

Bb F C E (Bb-M11? Bb-Aug11?) - Bb add #4 add 2 (could also be major or minor)

C# G B D# (C#-m11flat5?) - G aug add #4 (first inversion)

C# E B F# - C#min7 add 4

**BUT, there are a lot of ways to view these combinations, and the above is not exclusive.**